# BLE on C# Web App in Visual Studio

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, bluetooth-gatt

i´m looking forward to build a complete online Beacon Manager.
It should connect tp nearby BLE devices and register them for more editing.
I tried Bridge an Retype but it doesn´t support .Net Core and just destroy the project. ble.net is hard to use because i can´t find a good documentation.
I find only apps that register Beacons and then you can edit it from Browser, but i want it all in the Browser, any help ? Looking for working stuff since days...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "All in the browser".  Are you saying you want JavaScript to connect to the BLE Beacons?  If so, a .NET framework will not help.

Comment: I wanted to have an online Beacon Manager, but the possibiltys were realy rar for now, so i do an app to register the Beacon and a website to manage them.

Answer (score 0):

[Bluetooth Framework](https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm) currently supports .NET Stanbdard 2.0 and next version will support .NET Core 2.0. If you would like to test it out I can send you a test version. It works good on Windows Desktop platforms (including ASP.NET) but now we are fixing some issues to make it running well on Windows 10 IoT (Raspberry Pi).

Comment: That sounds really great, do you have a release date for this project ? It doesn´t make sense to me to aork now on it when it doesn´t support .NET Core and this is what i need :/ If your test version includes the Core support i would like to test it ! I will work to on iOt stuff with this, so i think it´s exactly what i need

Comment: It should be released till the end of this week. Yes, test version already supports .NET Core on Windows Desktop platforms. Also it works on Windows IoT Core platform but with few limitations/issues (not bugs just few small issues).

Comment: We have just released version with .NET Core support.